# Chinese and English combination for iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to JasperReports. I am wondering if it is possible to display a combination of Chinese and English characters in bold in iReport.

Here I'm sending wt i did so far,

```xml
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
    <![CDATA["This is to certify that <style pdfFontName='/rpt/ArialB.ttf' isBold='true'>"
    +URLDecoder.decode($V{varCompName})
    +" </style>is incorporated under the Labuan Companies Act 1990 on and from the <style pdfFontName='/rpt/ArialB.ttf' isBold='true'>"
    +$V{varDayCrtDt}+"</style> day of <style pdfFontName='/rpt/ArialB.ttf' isBold='true'>"
    +$V{varMonthCrtDt}
    +"</style>, in the year of <style pdfFontName='/rpt/ArialB.ttf' isBold='true'>"
    +$V{varYearCrtDt}
    +"</style> and that the company is "
    +$V{varlimitedby}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

If I remove, style tag for companyName its displaying Chinese and English chars, but if i keep style tag only printing English chars in bold its not printing Chinese chars.

Please help me on this.

Thanks
Bunny

Comment: What exporter (pdf, doc, docs, xls) did you use? You should use font with Asian languages support. You can read about the [Font Extensions](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html).

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply.I'm using exporter is pdf.I'm not understanding Font Extensions will you explain me briefly.So far i've used ArialB.ttf font can u refer me which font its going to support. Thanks Bunny.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to mix multiple fonts in the same text field in a PDF exported by JasperReports. Vote for the enhancement [here](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=4932).

After you vote for the enhancement, then you'll need to find a font that covers both the Chinese and English characters that you need.